# How to use the SQL Server integer division operator "\"?

Tags: sql-server

According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255271(v=sql.110).aspx:

```
\ Divides two numbers and returns an integer result.
```

However, I cannot figure out how to use it. All my attempts end up the same - the error

> Incorrect syntax near '\ 5'

when trying to do an integer division by 5.

So how do we use the damn thing?

Comment: Can you post the whole query you're trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that you posted is specific to SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services). You can use `\`operator in Reporting Services expressions, which is not the same as T-SQL.

T-SQL does not support `\` operator, only `/` operator. You can see the [list of valid arithmetic operators on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187716(v=sql.110).aspx)

If you are confused about what is Expression and what is T-SQL, expression is basically statement that you use in report, often to process or format the data. T-SQL on the other hand is the language which is used to execute queries and commands on SQL databases.

Comment: You can divide just change the \ for /

Comment: @Juan - Just keep in mind the `/` in T-SQL is basically a "floor" when dividing non-float/decimal/money data types.

Comment: Sorry Jason what do you mean by floor?

Comment: Integers can be divided too, the result data type will depend on the values in the division

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d3dd/1

You can divide like this

```
select 4/2
```

This will give you 2

If you are looking for to divide and get if any remainder then is %

See an example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d3dd/4